# Open.ics with Outlook 2013 to read items

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar, outlook-2013

This is specific to Office 2013.

In previous versions of Office (2010), I had a script which would download an .ics attachment and then save it to my calendar. After loading the .ics I then  iterate through the .ics file and copy all `AppointmentItem`'s to my calendar.

```
Dim oSharedFolder As Outlook.folder
Set oSharedFolder = _
    Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").OpenSharedFolder( _
    "C:\Temp\1421940003_event.ics")
```

However, in 2013 VBA the `OpenSharedFolder` method does not allow me to do this anymore, saying "The operation failed." In exploring the MSDN documentation I see:

> OpenSharedFolder - [This method does not support iCalendar appointment (.ics) files. To open iCalendar appointment files, you can use the OpenSharedItem method of the NameSpace object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867648.aspx)

Ok, great! They changed the name to OpenSharedItem instead (ignore their example using an .ics file.. which has the same error). However when I go there, I see:

> OpenSharedItem - [This method does not support iCalendar calendar (.ics) files. To open iCalendar calendar files, you can use the OpenSharedFolder method of the NameSpace object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869733.aspx)

So both these link to each other -- incorrectly, I might add, since both fail, even though *both examples say they work for ics files*.

My question is:

- How can I open an .ics file with Outlook 2013 vba?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of either parsing the ICS file explicitly in your code or using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author): it will let you import ICS files with a single event using `RDOAppointmentItem`.[Import](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm#methods)(..., olICal); multiple events in a single ICS file can be imported using [RDOFolder2](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).`Import`:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
set items = Folder.Import("c:\temp\MultipleItems.ics", olICal)
for each item in items
    debug.Print item.Subject
next
```